# Redirection cannot open for reading

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I ran the following command and I am not able to understand why I am getting this error :

```
tail /var/log/fontconfig.log 1 >> /home/myuser/b.log
tail: cannot open '1' for reading: No such file or directory
```

File `fontconfig.log` exists and directory `myuser` exists too.
However , this command works :

```
tail /var/log/fontconfig.log >> /home/myuser/b.log
```

Here , I have removed `1`. Can any body explain why I am getting this error ? Also, If we don't mention any standard file descriptors like I did not mentioned `1` what does it take then ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mention any file descriptor, it defaults to file descriptor `1` (standard output). If you **do** give an explicit descriptor, you must do so without whitespace before the `>>` operator. As noted in `man bash`:

```
   Appending Redirected Output
       Redirection of output in  this  fashion  causes  the  file  whose  name
       results  from  the expansion of word to be opened for appending on file
       descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if  n  is  not
       specified.  If the file does not exist it is created.

       The general format for appending output is:

              [n]>>word
```

So when you wrote

```
tail /var/log/fontconfig.log 1 >> /home/myuser/b.log
```

it tries to `tail` both `/var/log/fontconfig.log` and a *file named* `1`, and redirect the resulting standard output to `/home/myuser/b.log` : the error is because you don't have a file named `1` from which `tail` can read.